# Adding layered navigation to custom theme (magento)

Tags: magento, magento-1.5

How do I add/activate the layered navigation?

I've built out a custom magento theme that currently only shows the categories on the product listing page. I'd like it to now display the layered navigation but the problem is I can't seem to figure out how to show it. I think I screwed up when building it and the product list page references the top navigation instead.

Any change I make to my catalog.xml file or the view.phtml file to reference the layered navigation does not seem to generate any layered navigation code on the front end (and thus no layered navigation).

All categories are set up as Anchors and to display in the navigation and I'm stuck as to what else to try.

Answer (score 0):

try this on catelog.xml

```
<catalog_category_default translate="label">
<reference name="content">
    <block type="catalog/layer_view" name="catalog.contentnav" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml"/>
</reference>
```

Comment: I tried this and nothing happened. I think the issue must be in how I am referencing the navigation in /catalog/view.phtml, I've moved this over to magento.stackexchange and added links to view.phtml & catalog.xml

http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/37013/how-to-add-layered-navigation-to-custom-theme#comment50839_37013